# PHP FileUpload - Uploading more than 10000 files

Tags: php, file-upload

I have built a web application that will run locally within my organization.

Through a fileupload module, I am allowing the users to upload the images to a predefined folder in the server. Since, the users will be working with 1000's of images at the same time I should allow them to upload 1000's of files in one go.

The application resides on a Linux server running ubuntu, PHP5,apache2 & MySQL. I have made the following changes in php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
max_file_uploads = 10000
```

My understand of `upload_max_filesize` is the size of a single image and that of `max_file_uploads` is the number of files.   This works without a problem in my local machine, which is also a ubuntu with apache2,php5 and mysql.  However when the users try to upload the files, they were able to upload only 900 files at a time.

The users use windows machines to interact with the server.  How can I make the server to accept say 10000 files in a single upload.

Comment: If it works on your local machine but not on the server, can you compare the settings of both Apache and PHP? Maybe `max_input_vars` (default 1000) gets in the way?

Comment: Check `post_max_size` variable. You can set to 0 for unlimited post

Comment: @Anton Thank you...I tried this and many other options...nothing helped.

Comment: @Apricot, well, you can post via js by one file per post and process it on server side asynchronously (worth mention http://php.net/pthreads)

Answer (score 0):

That’s a lot of files to upload at once.

Perhaps you could create a JavaScript app that would process the uploads and split the grouped files into separate uploads.

Or choose a different protocol. HTTP isn’t meant for high volume uploads such as this. Have you considered using FTP?

How big is the average upload size? It could also be limitations of the web browser. I’m not sure if upload_max_filesize is per file or for the entirety of the upload. Try increasing the size as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response....since all the files were transferred from one location to another within the same network (LAN) i was hoping to do it with php file upload itself.  I will try increasing the max upload size as well

Comment: I did try increasing the max upload size...and other parameters as well.  But didn't work.  I cannot use FTP as there are certain image processing happens while upload.

Comment: You can use FTP and upload it to a directory. Then scan that directory with a PHP script for images, process them and move them to another directory after processing.

Comment: Another idea. Maybe you can try compressing the files into a ZIP archive and upload that for the PHP script to decompress once uploaded.